# Laravel - DELETE 500 server error

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I wanna try to set up a delete request with ajax and Laravel 5. My script works just the halfway, because it actually deletes the entry but returns a 500 server error. Any idea, what i am doing wrong?

**Clientside**

```
<input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">


<script>

$('.remove').click(function(){

    //Declaration
    var token = $('#token').val();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    //Delete request
    $.ajax({
        type:   'DELETE',
        url:    '/pv/' + id,
        data:   { _token :token },
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

**Serverside**

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $pv = PV::find($id);

    $pv->delete();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: do you get any additional details in log file ?

Comment: @KhanShahrukh Checked the apache and laravel log. Nothing

Comment: I should not ask this but your route method is delete right ?

Comment: Yep. I created a restful controller.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The only thing i need to change is the return from `true` to `"true"`. Forgot that communication between client and server is stringbased.